# Laravel validate with datetime-local

Tags: laravel, validation, datetime

I need some help with Laravel form validation:

blade:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="date[]">
```

validation:

```
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $after = Carbon::createFromDate(2025,01,01);

    return request()->validate([
        'name' => ['required'],
        'description' => ['required'],
        'date' => ['required', 'before:'. $now, 'after:'.$after]
    ]);
```

I think that should work, however doesn't matter what is the input value it ALWAYS throws and error. My guess would be that the date format doesn't match and Laravel can't do the comparison. I have basically the same comparison in a different form, but only with date type and that is working perfectly.

I found some similar question here, but nothing worked for me. I'm out of ideas. Does anyone else had the same problem?

Thanks for the answer in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the validation rules you've used for the `date` field, it makes perfect sense to always throw an error. The reason is that you want your `date` to be **before the current time** and at the same time, **after 2025-01-01** which cannot produce a truthful output.

What you need to do is reverse your rules values to be

```
'date' => 'required|array', // check date is set and is an array
'date.*' => ["before:$after", "after:$now"] // each element in the array needs to follow the before and after rules
```

This way, you ask each of your `date` values to be **after the current daytime** and **before 2025-01-01**.

Comment: Thanks fo the suggestion, but I tried that already and it's throws an error.

Every time I got an: The date must be a date after 2020-04-12 10:27:30 error. Doesn't matter what date value I use

Comment: Okay, so I found the problem, since I send an array to the backend (name='date[]', Laravel can't process the validation). I need to find a solution for validating an array